# Unknown port in videocassette recorder JVC HS-D320S

Tags: identification, port

I have an old videocassette recorder JVC HS-D320S, I want to ultimately try to digitalise some videocassettes, but I'm having troubling identifying the ports on the back.

[image]

---

<sup>PS: I'll clarify the question a bit more if you could tell me what those little grooves in the cable are called.
PPS: Is there a tag for videocassette recorders or something similar?</sup>

Comment: Looks like a SCART connector. Is that any help?

Comment: These used to be on every better TV and on every VCR in the nineties. I allow myself to infer that you were born after 1998.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it is not about electronics design. I am not sure *what* the question is about. VTC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are SCART connectors - one for input from a video source, one for output to a telly.

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCART